# Iterate through a list of files and copy them using python

Tags: python, loops, copy

I want to create a function that will iterate through a list to file names that I put in, and then when the conditions are met I want it to copy each subsequent file to a file named 'INPUT'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
file_list = [file1, file2, file3]
def queue():
    if condition1_met:
        for item in file_list:
            os.system('cp item INPUT')
        else:
            return queue()
```

However I just don't know what the best way is to iterate and then copy the file, since that os.system bit won't recognize 'item'.

Comment: Copying each item to `INPUT` means they each replace the previous version. Only the *last* such copy will remain.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, however I do want to preserve the original file.

Comment: Why, are you using os.system() for this operation? Wouldn't handling file objects entirely in python suffice?

Comment: I don't think you want that else clause after the for. It will always run (because there is no break in the for loop) and so queue() will keep calling itself and copying files until python hits its recursion limit. Did you really want recusion in this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace:

```
os.system('cp item INPUT')
```

by:

```
os.system('cp %s INPUT' % item)
```

So the value of the item iterator is substituted in the string and being executed as an OS call.

**Edited according comment:**

Better is to use shutil:

```
shutil.copyfile(item, 'INPUT')
```

This way no substition is needed.

Comment: Please use `shutil` for these operations.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Edited answer according your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code will copy each file to INPUT, overwriting INPUT each time:

```
import shutil

file_list = [file1, file2, file3]
def queue():
  if condition1_met:
    for item in file_list:
      shutil.copyfile(item, "INPUT")
    else:
      return queue()
```

If you want to append the content of the files to INPUT, then this should do the job:

### python 2.6 version

```
import contextlib

file_list = [file1, file2, file3]
def queue():
  if condition1_met:
    for item in file_list:
      with contextlib.nested(open(item,"r"), open("INPUT","a+")) as (src,dst):
        dst.writelines(src.readlines())
    else:
      return queue()
```

### python 2.7 version

```
file_list = [file1, file2, file3]
def queue():
  if condition1_met:
    for item in file_list:
      with open(item,"r"), open("INPUT","a+") as src,dst:
        dst.writelines(src.readlines())
    else:
      return queue()
```